# Hibernate query find if ids exist on some entity.list.ids

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have such case trying to query some ids if they exist on some entity list ex :

```
@Entity
class Person{
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  List<Job> jobList;
}

@Entity 
class Job{
  @Id
  long id;
  //otherfields...
}
```

Query trying to do :

`From Person p where :selectedJobIds exists in :(p.jobList.id)`

So I'm trying to find if each `Job` of person's jobs has id found in `selectedJobIds`

Is it doable on Hibernate or Am I forced to use subquery tried using `elements` with no luck

Comment: "So I'm trying to find if each Job of person's jobs has id found in selectedJobIds "
According to your requirement the query should be
<code>select job from Job job where job.id exists in :selectedJobIds</code>

Comment: @LêThọ The thing is I'm trying to select ``Persons`` by selected jobs ids

Comment: Is the relationship between Person and Job is ManyToMany ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in hibernate by using Criteria API too. Use add() method present for Criteria object to add restrictions for a criteria query.

For example:

```
Criteria cr= session.createCriteria(Job.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id",2);
List results= cr.list();
```